# Python - Text to List but not as strings

Tags: python, list, class, text, readline

I Have a text file containing class statements like so:

```
Person('John Smith','1st Street','1987')
Patient('Steve White','2nd Street','1976','456 132 768 128','11/14/17','St. Johns','Warren','309C')
Employee('Roger Marks','3rd Street','1991','192837465','2011')
Doctor('Paul Warren','4th Street','1967','918213665','2007','250000','Cardiology','17')
Staff('Mike Clark','5th Street','1983','285018539','2009','Custodian','Sanatation','18', 'Full')
```

When I enter them into a list using:

```
infile = open('ClassData.txt', 'r')
line = infile.readline()
for line in infile:
    pObjects.append(line)
```

I get them in quotes, for example:

```
pObjects = ["Person('John Smith','1st Street','1987')","Employee('Roger Marks','3rd Street','1991','192837465','2011')"]
```

What could I change to get them in there without the quotes so they can be pulled from the list and ran, like,

```
pObjects = [Person('John Smith','1st Street','1987'),Employee('Roger Marks','3rd Street','1991','192837465','2011')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
pObjects = map(ast.literal_eval, pObjects)
```

Comment: `pObjects = map(ast.literal_eval, pObjects)` was giving me an error but I did get it working using regular eval(), `pObjects.append(eval(line))`